# C# OleDBConnection to Access 2010 - Error: Not a valid filename

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2010, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

Thanks for taking the time to read!!!! Sorry I'm a complete Newbie....

So, I'm desperately trying to connect to a database on another computer through a VPN. When I change the code to point to the file locally, there are no problems, but when I try for the networked pc, I get An "unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll", "Additional information: Not a valid file name."

Here's the code, any thoughts would be super appreciated!!!! :)

```
private void btn_Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.Copy("\\\\User2-pc\\c\\RetailM\\That's Hot\\recent.mdb", "\\\\User2-pc\\c\\PHIL_REPORT_PROGRAM\\That's Hot\\recent_copy.mdb", true);

    btn_Load.Text = ("Loaded");
    progressBar1.Value = (100);
}

private void btnReadAccess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conAccess = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\\\User2-pc\\c\\PHIL_REPORT_PROGRAM\\That's Hot\\recent_copy.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;");

    string[] strArrays = this.datePickerFrom.Text.Split(new char[] { '/' });
    string[] strArrays1 = this.datePickerTo.Text.Split(new char[] { '/' });
    string[] text = new string[] { "SELECT Barcode,[description],cat1 ,cat2,discount as [Discount],cost_inc as [Price $],DocketLine.quantity as Sold, (rrp * DocketLine.quantity - discount ) as [Rev $], DocketLine.sales_tax as Goods_Tax FROM Docket,DocketLine,Stock WHERE Docket.docket_date >= #", strArrays[1], "/", strArrays[0], "/", strArrays[2], " ", this.timePickerFrom.Text, "# AND Docket.docket_date <= #", strArrays1[1], "/", strArrays1[0], "/", strArrays1[2], " ", this.timePickerTo.Text, "#  and DocketLine.docket_id = Docket.docket_id  and  DocketLine.stock_id= Stock.stock_id" };
    string str = string.Concat(text);
    OleDbDataAdapter daAccess = new OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand(str, conAccess));
    DataTable dataTable1 = new DataTable();
    daAccess.Fill(dataTable1);
    dgvAccess.DataSource = dataTable1;

    decimal num = new decimal(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.dgvAccess.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        num = num + Convert.ToDecimal(this.dgvAccess.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
    }
}
```

Thanks so much for all your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the path in quotes:

```
"\"\\\\User2-pc\\c\\RetailM\\That's Hot\\recent.mdb\"";
```

or use a straight folder name like, simply, `Hot`.

Comment: Thanks so much Gustav, but the straight folder name didn't work, what should I wrap in quotes? the source part of the OleDbConnection? If so... I get OleDbConnection conAccess = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="\\\\User2-pc\\c\\PHIL_REPORT_PROGRAM\\Hot\\recent_copy.mdb";Persist Security Info=False;"); Unexpected character '\' Any other ideas? Thanks so much again :)

Comment: I wrote above how to wrap the full path in quotes. It should be close to an copy-n-paste.

Comment: Hey Gustav, still no good.... It crashes at: dgvAccess.DataSource = dataTable1; which is where it happened before, any more thoughts? Your my hero btw :)

Comment: It seems related to the UNC path. Try mapping a drive letter to server\folder path and use that drive letter in your code.

Comment: Gustav, you are a genius and my hero!!!! Thanks so so so much, mapping fixed it completely!!!! Thanks again

Comment: Great. Have a nice weekend!